# How to query duplicate data which have been added more than 2 times within 5 minutes and have the same email address?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

I have my sample data in the database table as following.

```
id   email            created_at
1    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:01:30
2    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:02:20
3    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:03:30
4    new@mail.com     2016-01-01 02:56:00
5    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:04:30
6    new@mail.com     2016-01-01 02:59:08
7    new@mail.com     2016-01-01 03:01:24
8    i@mail.com       2016-01-01 04:20:30
9    i@mail.com       2016-01-01 04:23:29
10   new@mail.com     2016-01-01 04:30:08
11   i@mail.com       2016-01-01 04:25:29
12   new@mail.com     2016-01-01 04:32:08
13   e@mail.com       2016-01-01 05:16:30
14   i@mail.com       2016-01-01 06:00:00
15   aa@email.com     2017-07-17 15:03:00
16   aa@email.com     2017-07-17 15:04:00
17   aa@email.com     2017-07-17 15:08:01
```

I run the following SQL query, provided by Strawberry.

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM my_table x
JOIN my_table y
ON y.id <> x.id
AND y.email = x.email
AND y.created_at 
BETWEEN x.created_at - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE 
AND x.created_at + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE 
GROUP
BY x.id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

And I get the following records.

```
id   email            created_at
1    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:01:30
2    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:02:20
3    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:03:30
5    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:04:30
6    new@mail.com     2016-01-01 02:59:08
8    i@mail.com       2016-01-01 04:20:30
9    i@mail.com       2016-01-01 04:23:29
11   i@mail.com       2016-01-01 04:25:29
16   aa@email.com     2017-07-17 15:04:00
```

What I want to retrieve are the following records because they have the same email address. It means the same records to me and they have been inserted more than 2 times within 5 minute.

```
id   email            created_at
1    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:01:30
2    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:02:20
3    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:03:30
5    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:04:30
8    i@mail.com       2016-01-01 04:20:30
9    i@mail.com       2016-01-01 04:23:29
11   i@mail.com       2016-01-01 04:25:29
```

How can I write a sql query to get only the records which have been added more than 2 times within 5 minute?

Comment: @Strawberry I am sorry. My bad. 11 is also included, either on sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a simpler way, but this would appear to return the result you're seeking...

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
           FROM service_request a
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT x.* 
                     , MAX(y.created_at) AS range_end
                  FROM service_request x
                  JOIN service_request y
                    ON y.email = x.email
                   AND y.id >= x.id 
                   AND y.created_at <= x.created_at + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
                 GROUP
                    BY x.id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
              ) b
             ON b.email = a.email 
            AND a.created_at BETWEEN b.created_at AND b.range_end;
```

Comment: Why did you exclude IDs 11 and 12?

Comment: @Strawberry: where can I put the condition that I only retrieve those records in case the duplicate records are more than 2 within 5 minutes? If 2 records have been added with the same email within 5 minutes, no need to retrieve them, only if there are three and upper within 5 minutes. Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: @Strawberry: I did try your query. It solves all the problem. But there is another issue with that. I did update my sample DB to express the issue. In case there are three duplicate records (id15,16,17) and id17 is at 15:08:00, your query returns the record id16 ONLY. If id17 is at 15:09:00, everything works perfect. How can I solve that? I would like to say that your sql skill is so high to come so far. You are so close! Thanks bro! I hope you can help me finish this. I appreciate that!!

Comment: @Strawberry why 15,16,17 are excluded because from my sample db, when the third record (id17) is at the edge of 5 minutes, your query returns only the id16. 15,16,17 are excluded to express the issue. Please see the created_at time of those records.

Comment: @Strawberry I think you are confusing by looking at my second database. I was talking about my first database sample. To prevent confusing, I deleted my second database sample. My apologise!! Please read my previous comment again and focus only on the records id15,16,17 since your query already retrieves other records correctly. Thank you!!

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry about that. This is because my first database sample was not prefect to meet all the requirements. E.g. with my first database sample your query works perfect but I realised that the duplicate records will not always come right after each other. Thus I changed my database sample. That is an example why I made it a bit confusing now. I am sorry. Hope you still want to help me since you are so close now!

Comment: If and when you update your question, I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: @Strawberry I just updated my question. Hope you still want to help. I appreciate that! Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
Select T1.*
from emails T1
inner join emails T2 on
T1.email=T2.email and T2.id=T1.id+1 and T2.created_at<T1.created_at + Interval 5 minute
union 
Select T2.*
from emails T1
inner join emails T2 on
T1.email=T2.email and T2.id=T1.id+1 and T2.created_at<T1.created_at + Interval 5 minute
order by ID
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b16171/12

Comment: Hi it looks good and it is so close. But I want to select only the records that are inserted more than 2 times within a certain of minutes. How to add that limitation?

Comment: Does this query return extra rows ?

Comment: yes It returns the same rows several times. What I want to retrieve are records that have been added within 5 minutes more than two times, thus 3 and up. And have the same email address. Please help me with this! Thank in advanced!!

Comment: I updated the query, is it ok for you? if not I'll try to fiddle it.

Comment: thank you for trying to help me. Unfortunately I get all the records when trying the above query. I hope you have another solution for me. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Since there are no other answers, I updated my query again, hope this will be fine

Comment: I have tried your query. It looks better but unfortunately it also retrieves the record that its email is duplicated but the created_at is far from others. I hope you can come up with another query to help me. Otherwise I will use your current query for this moment. But really don't want you to give up your attempt since you are so close and really wanted to help me. I appreciate that and thanks a lot!

Comment: I updated the query, it will work now: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b16171/12
You need to add rows with IDs 11 and 12 in expected results as they have same Email and less than 5minutes between creation dates.

Comment: This relies on a contiguous sequence, which seems vulnerable. Also, it misinterprets the requirement (as I did). The result set provided by the OP is correct.

Comment: @haytem Your query works perfect if the duplicate records come right after each other. But for a bit realistic, the duplicate records would not come right after each other all the time since different users might insert the data at the same time. In that case, your query retrieves only the duplicate records which come right after each other.I would miss ONE duplicate record which doesn't come right after each other, but also within 5 min. I updated my sample db to show that records id1,2,3 will be retrieved but id5 will be missed,even it's also a duplicate record & was inserted within 5 min.

Comment: @OConnor: Strawberry's answer will work for you, did you try it?

Comment: @haytem Yes I did try Strawberry's query and also put my comment that. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
either you need to remove ID = 4 or to add Id = 11 and ID = 12 and check this:


select  distinct
        id,
        Email,
        Created_at
from    (
            select  distinct
                    t1.id,
                    t1.email,
                    t1.created_at
            from    MyTable t1
                    join MyTable t2 on
                        t2.email = t1.email
            where   datediff(mi, t1.created_at, t2.created_at) > 0
                    and datediff(mi, t1.created_at, t2.created_at) <= 5
            union all
            select  distinct
                    t2.id,
                    t2.email,
                    t2.created_at
            from    MyTable t1
                    join MyTable t2 on
                        t2.email = t1.email
            where   datediff(mi, t1.created_at, t2.created_at) > 0
                    and datediff(mi, t1.created_at, t2.created_at) <= 5
        ) x
```

Comment: RDBMS is MySQL, not SQL Server, so your syntax in incorrect.